# Retrieving second level friendships from a table and excluding first level friends

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure for a table `Friendship`:

```
| user varchar(255) | friend varchar(255) |
```

How can I retrieve a list of second level friends (i.e. John is friends with Adam who is friends with Steve, so Steve is a second level friend to John)?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f2.friend AS FriendOfFriend
FROM Friendship f
INNER JOIN Friendship f2 ON f.friend = f2.user
```

There's some detail missing from your question, so these joins may need to be adjusted.  I'm assuming friends are also users.

Comment: I assumed the friend in the original row is the first level friend, so you would be returning third level friends. You also do not exclude the second level friends who are also first level friends - which the question seems to imply is required.

Comment: I corrected the query to return 2nd level friends.  I assumed the part about excluding first level friends meant that f.friend should not be returned, just f2.friend ?  OP would need to clarify.

Comment: I would also add DISTINCT to remove duplicates & possibly check for the original user who may very well appear as a second level friend of himself. You are right that OP needs to clarify exactly what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following four rows of sample data:

```
| user | friend |
+------+--------+
| John  | Sam    |
| John  | Adam   |
| Adam  | Steve  |
| Steve | George |
```

In this example, John is friends with Adam, who is friends with Steve, so John and Steve are second level friends. To get that, we must first get a list of all John's friends, like this:

```
SELECT friend
FROM friendship
WHERE user = 'John';
```

Note that this makes the assumption 'John' is always the user. If John is sometimes 'friend', you'll need a union to get a complete list.

Now, we have a list of Adam and Sam. We need to get a list of their friends. We can do so by doing another join:

```
SELECT f.friend AS firstLevel, fs.friend AS secondLevel
FROM friendship f
JOIN friendship fs ON fs.user = f.friend AND f.user = 'John';
```

This will give us a list of John's second level friends, and who the first level friend is. Now, there are a few things to consider:

What if The same friend appears twice? Let's say, Sam is also friends with Steve. We will get the following rows:

```
| Adam | Steve |
| Sam  | Steve |
```

To avoid that, we can just eliminate our select to the second level friend and use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs.friend
FROM friendship f
JOIN friendship fs ON fs.user = f.friend AND f.user = 'John';
```

If you ever need to expand this further, you can just add another join, and make sure it relates to the previous one. So, to get a third level connection, which in this example is George, we can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fss.friend AS thirdLevel
FROM friendship f
JOIN friendship fs ON fs.user = f.friend AND f.user = 'John'
JOIN friendship fss ON fss.user = fs.friend;
```

All of the above examples are demonstrated on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96960/2).

Comment: The original question specifies excluding first level friends - you can get the situation where a second level friend can also be a first level friend - also the original user could appear as a second level friend of himself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers the issues I have raised to other answers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user, b.friend
FROM Friendship a
JOIN Friendship b ON a.friend=b.user
WHERE a.user <> b.friend
AND NOT b.friend IN (SELECT c.friend FROM Friendship c WHERE a.user=c.user)
ORDER BY a.user
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84091/1

The first part of the Where clause rules out someone being his own second level friend, the second part filters out second level friends who are also first level friends.